# ConstraintLayout 2 TextView first one ellipsize

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

**UPDATE**

I achieved this behavior with following things:

**txtFullName**

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
```

**btnFollow and btnUnfollow**

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have an `XML` layout which is parent layout is `ConstraintLayout` and inside

```
       -- txtFullName -- (btnFollow | btnUnfollow ) --       
Avatar ----------------------------------------------- btnPrimaryAction
       -- txtTitle -----------------------------------
```

I want this:

[image: Long txtFullname okay]

But I got this with my xml

[image: Long txtFullName not okay]

When `txtFullName` is long, it is overlapping `btnFollow` or `btnUnfollow` and these buttons are not showing on screen. I want `txtFullName` to be **ellipsize** when it is long. I tried to use `ConstraintLayout`'s Flow but it didn't work well too.

My layout constraints can be shown below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFullName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="?attr/textColorMarineBlue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textButtonBarrierStart"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imgAvatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Long Full Name is overlapping btnFollow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnFollow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Follow"
        android:textColor="?attr/textColorAzure"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/txtFullName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnPrimaryAction"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/txtFullName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnUnfollow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Unfollow"
        android:textColor="?attr/textColorGreyishBrown"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/txtFullName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnPrimaryAction"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/txtFullName" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/textButtonBarrierStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="start"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="btnFollow,btnUnfollow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="?attr/textColorGreyishBrown"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnPrimaryAction"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imgAvatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtFullName"
        tools:text="Title" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/secondColumnEndBarrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="btnFollow,btnUnfollow,txtTitle" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPrimaryAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/secondColumnEndBarrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Action" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I achieve this UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a couple of attributes:

- In `txtFullName` to have match constraints width, so that its width can't exceed the barrier, and allow it to add the ellipsize just before the barrier.

  ```
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  ```
- In `btnFollow` & `btnUnfollow` use `layout_constraintWidth_min` with `wrap` value so that they can make sure that they always take the preference of wrapping their contents even when the width matches the constraints with `0dp`

  ```
  app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"
  ```

Preview now:

[image]

Comment: `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"` is deprecated and was replaced by `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`

Comment: `layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"` and `layout_constrainedWidth="true"` are both worked with `layout_width="0dp"` on `txtFullName`. Thanks for the answers, I appreciate it @che10 @Zain

Comment: @che10 Thanks for that .. Do you have some documentation reference for that deprecation?

Comment: @Zain My bad. I got confused. I mistook it as `layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
` which was recently deprecated. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the other answer either you can either set `layout_width` to `0dp` in your `txtFullName` or you can add the following flag too in your `txtFullName`

```xml
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

As follows

```xml
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFullName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        android:textColor="?attr/textColorMarineBlue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textButtonBarrierStart"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imgAvatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Long Full Name is overlapping btnFollow" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Use

```
layout_width="0dp"
```

instead of `layout_width="wrap_content"` for the TextView with id *txtFullName* as well.

Comment: `layout_width="0dp"` didn't work well without `layout_constrainedWidth="true`. I added constraintWidth and it works right now